Playwright unable to capture click button : Unexpected token "48" while parsing selector "#M0:48::btn[17]" in sap web app
I want capture the below button as in snapshot (Get Variant):
Image_1
But getting error as Unexpected token "48" while parsing selector "#M0:48::btn[17]"
Below is the code:
Sch_6 = page.wait_for_selector('#M0:48::btn[17]')
Sch_6.click(timeout=60000)

Please advise.

A runnable [mcve] would be good, because there might be a better way to achieve whatever your underlying goal is, and the HTML should be provided as text. In any case, try page.wait_for_selector('[id="M0:48::btn[17]"]') or page.wait_for_selector(r'#M0\:48\:\:btn\[17\]') per Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector.

You can use an attribute selector or escape the special characters:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.43.0


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(r'<div id="M0:48::btn[17]">foo</div>')
    el = page.wait_for_selector(r'#M0\:48\:\:btn\[17\]')
    print(el.text_content()) # => foo
    el = page.wait_for_selector('[id="M0:48::btn[17]"]')
    print(el.text_content()) # => foo
    browser.close()


Thanks for the code revision. I am doing playwirght first time. So, I am not able understand below line--What does this line do?-->>  page.set_content(r'foo')

Also, my objective is to click on the button, whose id = "M0:48::btn[17]"   Should I go with the code as below. Please adivse.  --- >>> page.set_content(r'foo')
el = page.wait_for_selector(r'#M0:48::btn[17]')
el.click()

I'm setting the page by hand for the purpose of making a complete, runnable example. Don't use set_content in your case, just the selector. It doesn't make sense to overwrite your entire live page with one contrived HTML element. foo usually means "this is a placeholder for demonstration" in programming.

Approach 1:
el = page.wait_for_selector('[id="M0:48::btn[17]"]')
el.click(timeout=60000)
Error message –
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Run_2.py", line 32, in 
el = page.wait_for_selector('[id="M0:48::btn[17]"]')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api_generated.py", line 8349, in wait_for_selector

Approach 2:
el = page.wait_for_selector(r'#M0:48::btn\[17\]')
el.click(timeout=60000)Error message – Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Run_2.py", line 32, in  el = page.wait_for_selector(r'#M0:48::btn\[17\]') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\XXXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api_generated.py", line 8349, in wait_for_selector self._sync(
–

Have tried both approaches (1 and 2 as above) as suggested - but the button is not getting selected/clicked. Please advise.

First of all, does my minimal example work for you? If not, then there's some fundamental setup problem, like a different version of Playwright or something. Please confirm that. If the minimal example does work, then there's probably some behavior on your actual site getting in the way, like an iframe, shadow DOM, cloudflare block, JS timing behavior, visibility or something like that. In that case, please share the actual site.

BTW, I don't think your stack traces show the actual error. Please share the whole stack trace, preferably as an edit to your post.

Using playwright 1.43.0

I upgraded to 1.43.0 and this still works as expected. Feel free to respond to my above comments if you still need help (report whether my code works or not, share a [mcve] and/or full stack trace).

Yes. I checked. Each HTML page has an iframe as "<iframe name = "application-XXX-display-iframe>" embedded in every page. If this is the case, is there no way around to automate such cases.

What options do I have? Please advise.

I'll need a [mcve] of the actual page/code and a full stack trace to be able to help further.
